# Which algorithm uses fewer operations - $n^2 2^n$ vs $n!$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

If we have two different algorithms for solving a problem, and to solve a problem of size $n$, the first algorithm uses exactly $n^2 2^n$ operations and the second algorithm uses exactly $n!$ operations. As $n$ grows, which algorithm uses fewer operations and why?  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: See also [How to prove that $n^2(2^n) / n! \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309431/how-to-prove-that-n22n-n-to-0-as-n-to-infty).

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?  It says $n! \approx \frac {n^n}{e^n}\sqrt {2 \pi n}$ and is more than accurate enough for your needs-within a factor of $(1+\frac 1{12n})$ and a tiny smidge.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Prove that
$$\dfrac{n^2 2^n}{n!} \to 0$$

Comment: How?  And what does this prove?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at $$u_n=\frac {n^22^n}{n!}$$ What does it approach?

Comment: I guess 0.......?

Comment: Consider $u_{n + 1}/u_n$...